# R rbind a data frame to a previous dataframe (based on condition)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, conditional-statements, rbind

I have a list that contains more then 17,000  data frames.

I can’t bind them all together before extracting data, since each df represents information about one individual.

Some dfs are just a continuation to the preceding df (ex. Df[[1001]]  is the continuation of data presented on Df[[1000]].

Is there a way to bind by row one df to a df indexed  immediately before (based on a condition)?

**Exemple input:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(text = c("Name: Joseph", "a", "b"))
df2 <- data.frame(text = c("c", "d"))
df3 <- data.frame(text = c("Name: Paul", "e", "f"))
df4 <- data.frame(text = c("Name: Ian", "g", "h"))
df5 <- data.frame(text = c("k", "l"))

df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
```

**The desired outcome:**

```
[[1]] text "Name: Joseph", "a", "b", "c", "d" 

[[2]] text "Name: Paul", "e", "f"

[[3]] text "Name: Ian", "g", "h", "k", "l"
```

I can isolate the dfs  that must be bound with this code:

```
library(purrr)

continue <- keep(df_list, ~all(!str_detect(.x$text, "Na.+")))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi akrum. I'll edit the information:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) methods

1. Bind the `list` elements together to a single dataset - `bind_rows`
2. Create a grouping column based on the presence of 'Name:' substring in 'text'
3. Paste the elements together in 'text' - `toString` by the group created in 2
4. Extract the summarised output as a vector with `pull`
5. Convert to `list` - `as.list` if needed

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
bind_rows(df_list) %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(text, 'Name:'))) %>%  
   summarise(out = toString(text)) %>% 
   pull(out) %>%
   as.list
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "Name: Joseph, a, b, c, d"

[[2]]
[1] "Name: Paul, e, f"

[[3]]
[1] "Name: Ian, g, h, k, l"
```

NOTE: The above output is a single string.  If we need as a `vector` just wrap the `list` instead of `toString`

```
bind_rows(df_list) %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(text, 'Name:'))) %>%  
   summarise(out = list(text)) %>% 
   pull(out)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "Name: Joseph" "a"            "b"            "c"            "d"           

[[2]]
[1] "Name: Paul" "e"          "f"         

[[3]]
[1] "Name: Ian" "g"         "h"         "k"         "l"
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R option -

```
tmp <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
split(tmp, cumsum(grepl('Name', tmp$text)))

#$`1`
#          text
#1 Name: Joseph
#2            a
#3            b
#4            c
#5            d

#$`2`
#        text
#6 Name: Paul
#7          e
#8          f

#$`3`
#        text
#9  Name: Ian
#10         g
#11         h
#12         k
#13         l
```